# jQuery listener for click on touchscreens?

Tags: jquery, touch

What's the simplest way to detect a click event with jquery for touchscreens only? I know that modenizr could be used to achieve this but as I only need this basic functionality I was wondering if it could be done with jquery only.

Comment: Could you be more specific by click event, do you mean the actualy 'click' event on the browser, or do you mean finger on the screen and such

Comment: I think click can detect the touch in the browser .. If you want more specific touch events like touch start , touch end.. You can ue mouseup, mousedown etc..

Comment: @Likwid_T I want to detect a click but not a swipe for a touchscreen. I dont want to detect a click for desktop users. Thanks

Comment: Then you have to detect the browser  and OS. Based on that you can write  touch event  specifically for mobile devices...

Comment: @Anish would it not be better to detect the touch screen feature? Can this be done easily without a library like modenizr?

Comment: Could you use the touchstart or touchend events, they won't fire on desktops that use mice

Comment: I haven't tried in mobile devices. But i tried jquerymobile. It May be helpful..But you have to write a code for desktop and mobile version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery onMouseover/onClick for Touchscreen users (ie iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430568/jquery-onmouseover-onclick-for-touchscreen-users-ie-ipad)

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window || "ontouch" in window) {
   // put click listener here
}
```

Seems to work fine.